# How to convert asciidoc to pdf?

Tags: asciidoc

I attempted to convert my `mybook.adoc` to `mybook.pdf` using `pandoc`, and got the following error.

```
$ pandoc -s mybook.adoc -t asciidoc -o mybook.pdf
pandoc: cannot produce pdf output with asciidoc writer
```

Is there another tool that I should use instead of or in concert with `pandoc`?
How can I convert asciidoc to pdf?

Comment: pandoc indicates [here](https://pandoc.org/installing.html) "For PDF output, you’ll also need to install LaTeX", so perhaps `asciidoc` is the wrong tool and you need to use a pandoc LaTeX tool of some sort or something?

Comment: See my [graphical user interface-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70486172/8138591), this is the easiest and most convenient solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate single PDF from multiple Asciidoc files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443615/generate-single-pdf-from-multiple-asciidoc-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now realize the ideal route from asciidoc to pdf is to first convert the asciidoc to docbook. This employs the intended sphere of asciidoc and a docbook->pdf converter using each in its separate area of concern.

Furthermore, instead of `pandoc` I have found that when mathematical formulas are included, it was easier to use `dblatex` for docbook->pdf conversion. Thus my conversion pipeline is the following:

> **asciidoc** -> *asciidoctor* -> **docbook** -> *dblatex* -> **pdf**

A sample make file:

```
make: my.adoc
  asciidoc -b docbook my.adoc
  dblatex my.xml
```

[This discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9204352) page suggests that asciidoc is primarily designed to compile to docbook.

Comment: I'm using asciidoc/dosbook for many years and I agree regarding asciidoc. But when using asciidoctor it is quite different: The recommended way is to use the gradle-plugin.

Answer (score 20):

**Prerequisites**: all that’s needed is Ruby (1.9.3 or above)

**Install** a native PDF converter for AsciiDoc - [Asciidoctor PDF](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-pdf/):

```
gem install asciidoctor-pdf --pre
```

**Run**:

```
asciidoctor-pdf mybook.adoc
```

You should get the file mybook.pdf in the same directory.

Comment: I used snap on Ubuntu to install ruby. Error: `Command 'asciidoctor-pdf' not found, but can be installed with: apt install ruby-asciidoctor-pdf`. So I removed snap ruby and used `sudo apt`. Works.

Comment: If you have [nix](https://nixos.org/) installed, just use [`nix-shell -p asciidoctor-with-extensions`](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=23.11&show=asciidoctor-with-extensions&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=asciidoctor-pdf) to enter a sub-shell that has `asciidoctor-pdf` ready to use.

Answer (score 19):

If you have Docker installed, you can use the [AsciiDoctor Docker Image](https://github.com/asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor#asciidoctor-docker-container). Then you can use the image interactively or in batch mode as explained below:

Prerequisites

1. Install Docker
2. Install the Docker image:

   ```sh
   $ docker pull asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor
   ```

Create the pdf by executing the following command:

```sh
$ cd [directory to where my book.adoc is located]
$ docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/documents/ asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor asciidoctor-pdf mybook.adoc
```

### Explanation

- `docker run` starts a Docker container
- `--rm` cleanup - removes the Docker container after the command has been executed
- `-v` [mount a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) to the image
- `$(pwd)` get the path to the current directory, e.g. the value of `[directory to where my book.adoc is located]` above
- `documents` the name of the mounted volume in the running container
- `asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor` the name of the Docker image that is used to create the Docker container
- `asciidoctor-pdf` the command that actually triggers the pdf generation
- `mybook.adoc` the name of the AsciiDoc source file to generate the pdf from

See also the [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) documentation

Comment: On windows, `$(pwd)` doesn't work in the command line so I used `docker run --rm -v "%cd%:/documents/" asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor asciidoctor-pdf mybook.adoc` instead

Answer (score 15):

If you're using Visual Studio Code with [AsciiDoc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asciidoctor.asciidoctor-vscode) extension, `Ctrl + SHFT + P` (or `Shift ⇧ + Cmd ⌘ + P` in macOS) and type `AsciiDoc: Export document as PDF`.

You will need to have `asciidoctor-pdf` or `wkhtmltopdf` installed according to the [command instructions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asciidoctor.asciidoctor-vscode#export-as-pdf).

Comment: I have my document organised into several files. For me VS Code fails to load images - for some reason it looks for them in a completely different location.

Answer (score 3):

AsciiDoc has a couple of toolchains that will render PDFs from AsciiDoc source. You can use the Ruby-based AsciiDoc -> Prawn -> PDF [toolchain](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-pdf/) developed by Asciidoctor, or you can use the older AsciiDoc -> DocBook -> FOP [toolchain](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/chunked/ch05.html). These are rendering/publishing procedures, whereas Pandoc mainly provides for conversion and is best for converting from one o another type of source format.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to convert AsciiDoc document to PDF is as follows -

- Open [AsciiDocLive](https://asciidoclive.com/edit/scratch/1)
- Paste your document in the editor and see the preview
- save it as HTML
- Open any online HTML to PDF convertor
- Upload your newly generated HTML file
- Convert to PDF and download it.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have AsciiDoc plugin in Intellij, here is the way you can generate -

1. create the adoc file ex - "tktds-dhs-e2e-gcp.adoc" and write your content.. or you may already have adoc file..
2. At top where file is opened in editor, click on PDF or HTML button to generate .pdf or .html files {need to click 1 at a time} refer below image -

[image]

3. Further you can find pdf / html file in same directory, refer below image -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following @Remis's answer, I used asciidoctor's pdf backend.

I could not figure out how to install `asciidoctor-pdf` on nixos, but managed to [find](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/24293) the following alternative which worked:

```
asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-pdf -b pdf or asciidoctor-pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workflow, which I use a lot, is to create HTML from your AsciiDoc file using the AsciiDoctor processor, linking a custom CSS stylesheet with print styling rules:

```
asciidoctor -a stylesheet=path-to-stylesheet.css file.adoc
```

You can then open the HTML file in your browser and print to PDF.

For more advanced styling, such as page numbering, headers, footers, page breaks and columns, you can use PrinceXML (or other similar products). This is a commandline processor that will convert the HTML file to PDF using the styling rules in the CSS used by the HTML file. PrinceXML applies styling rules that are in the CSS3 standard but which aren't yet supported by browsers, allowing you to create finely styled layouts.