# Generate single PDF from multiple Asciidoc files

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I'm trying to convert my existing asciidoc documentation into pdf. Asciidoctor-pdf seems quite easy and I'm able to convert single files into pdf.

```
asciidoctor-pdf -a pdf-theme='./theme/styles.yml' -a pdf-fontsdir='GEM_FONTS_DIR, theme/fonts/' 01-intro.adoc
```

But my docs are spread across many files. I want do create a single pdf from all those files. Does anyone know how to do this?

Secondly I don't want the generated pdf to be located next du the adoc file. I want to specify a target path.

I'd appreciate every hint. Thanks and best regards. Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most convenient way is to use the VSCode editor with the [AsciiDoc extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asciidoctor.asciidoctor-vscode) installed. This extension is developed by the same team that develops the [AsciiDoctor](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-vscode) text processor. This is a **GUI-based approach** to solve all your problems so I'm pretty sure u're gonna love it.

**(Step 1)** After the extension is installed, use the keyboard shortcut `Cmd` + `,` to go to the settings and then enter `asciidoc.use_asciidoctorpdf` in the search bar and tick the check box (see the demonstration below)

[image: Enable asciidoctor-pdf for the VSCode AsciiDoc extension]

**(Step 2)** To create a single pdf file from multiple `.adoc` files, just simply put all of them in a single `.adoc` file with `include::directory-to-the-adoc-file.adoc[]` (see the illustration below)

[image: Code example]

**(Step 3)** Press `F1`, then type in `as pdf` and hit `Enter` to export this single `.adoc` file as a single PDF file, **this will allow u to specify the target export directory for the PDF**. Please be patient and wait for a few seconds for the export to complete, the editor will immediately inform u as soon as the export is complete (see the image at the bottom)

[image: Export PDF]

[image: Export complete]

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to work with includes?

Just add to your document "01-intro.adoc" an any position this line:

```
include::02-next-file.adoc[]
```

When you build the `01-intro.adoc` with your regular command, the contents of `02-next-file.adoc` will be put to the position of the include line. Using this method we create a file with many includes and just build that file. We're very happy with that.

Comment: thanks for the info. I think includes work. but still i cannot set a target directory.

Comment: Just set -D DIR or --destination-dir DIR to set the destination output directory (default: directory of source file).